# (Ubuntu Server) Why does /usr/bin/node --version show v6.0.0 when /usr/bin/nodejs --version show v4.3.3?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, node.js

I recently had nodejs v6.0.0 installed.  I ran
    `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`
and reinstalled the LTS version using
    `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

After reinstalling I ran
    `sudo rm /usr/bin/node`

And re-created the symbolic link using
    `sudo ln -sv /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

Now running either with the --version parameter shows different versions...
Thanks ahead of time for any assistance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is no longer answerable.  http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6776/how-should-we-handle-questions-that-dont-have-a-satisfactory-answer-but-cant-b/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Server reboot solved the issue!  Should've tried this first.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that `/usr/bin/nodejs --version` and `/usr/bin/node` are showing different versions?

My first thought is to check with `which APP_NAME` to check that no other executable is in the path, maybe some standalone version, maybe from outside the package manager, is running instead.

Comment: Just seen your answer - probably was the $PATH not cleaning up!